# Django Rest Framework Custom JWT authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I created a Django app in which I want to be able to authenticate users by checking not only the username and password, but also a specific field in a related model. The custom request body I want to `POST` to the endpoint is:

```
payload = { 'username': user, 'password': password, 'app_id': uuid4}
```

I am using `djangorestframework-simplejwt` module to get the access token.

**models.py**

```
class Application(models.Model):

    app_name  = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    app_id    = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.app_name

class ProfileApp(models.Model):

    user       = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    app        = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expires_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=15))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.app.app_name + " | "  + self.user.username
```

Is it possible to override the `TokenObtainPairView` from `rest_framework_simplejwt` to only authenticate an user if the `expires_on` date is still not expired? Or is there an architecture problem by doing it like this?

Comment: Does your urls file currently just use the default `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()`?

Comment: Yes, just using the default `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom serializer that inherits from `TokenObtainPairSerializer`, and extending the `validate` method to check for custom field values. There is no architecture problem if you are careful to not override necessary functionality of the parent class.

Here is an example:

```py
import datetime as dt
import json
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView



class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        try:
            request = self.context["request"]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            request_data = json.loads(request.body)
            username = request_data.get("username")
            app_id = request_data.get("app_id")

            profile_has_expired = False
            try:
                profile = ProfileApp.objects.get(user__username=username, app__app_id=app_id)
            except ProfileApp.DoesNotExist:
                profile_has_expired = True
            else:
                profile_has_expired = dt.date.today() > profile.expires_on
            finally:
                if profile_has_expired:
                    error_message = "This profile has expired"
                    error_name = "expired_profile"
                    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(error_message, error_name)
        finally:
            return super().validate(attrs)


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Then use `MyTokenObtainPairView` in place of `TokenObtainPairView` in your urls file.

Also since `User` and `ProfileApp` share a one-to-one field, it looks like you can get away with not using the `"app_id`" key/field at all.

Original source file: https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/04376b0305e8e2fda257b08e507ccf511359d04a/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py

Comment: With some adjustments (`request.body` to `request.data`) and making the `datetime` comparison timezone-aware , I've made it to work as desired. Thank you!